# URl action template password and email verification problem, when i custom one URL it custom too in the other template and vice versa

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase templates for authentication, and I have a problem when I change the URL action(i put a custom one with the url of my project) for password reset and email verification. The issue is that when I change the URL in the password reset template, it also changes in the email verification template and vice versa.

Do you guys have any suggest?

Thanks for your time

i didnt have this problem 3 months ago

Comment: did you contacted firebase support ?